# How do I set up a new Drupal instance with all the modules from a previous one?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I had a temporary instance of drupal set up with lots of modules. I now have a new instance of Drupal and I want to install all the same modules, but I can only see how to do it with the GUI admin interface, which is frankly, horrifically clunky and unwieldy.

Is there another way to do this without spending half a day manually installing them again?

I've only heard of Drush, but I'm not sure how to set this up on windows, so this might not be the best answer. Everything I search for online (e.g. 'Export drupal modules') points me back to a 'modules that exports nodes etc.', not a 'mechanism for exporting modules'.

I've also found something called [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/node/1195682) but I can't tell if this is for modules or just nodes.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the concept of drupal [distributions](https://www.drupal.org/developing/distributions) comes in.

Yes you will need drush, a [make file](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432374) with the modules you need and a profile that installs these modules upon site-install.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't want to create a distribution though. The whole Drush/Make file/distributions malarkey looks like it's more hassle than it's worth (for me at least). I'll wait a little longer for other answers but I may just go with doing it manually.

Comment: If you find yourself downloading and installing the same modules again and again, make files are certainly the way to go

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is copy the module folders from your previous Drupal instance to new one. This will do (but I don't suggest it). But if you do so then you need to enable all your modules from GUI admin interface. Another glitch would be that if there is any update to the module then you will not get the updated module.

But I suggest it's best to use **drush** and it will give you more functionality which I cannot list you here.

[Installing Drush on Windows](https://www.drupal.org/node/594744)

also see this nice tutorial on [OStraining](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drush/)

**EDIT:**

This is nice and simple tutorial to setup drush on windows [Installing Drush on Windows - 1](http://ninjagirl.com/posts/2010/06/installing-drush-windows). Hope this helps to you.

Comment: The OS Training link looks like it's Linux specific, but otherwise this is super helpful. Thanks. I don't think I can find my modules folder, or even connect via Drush to the instance of drush I want to *copy from* as it's cloud hosted (?). I may have to give up, but this would otherwise have worked I think.